# Insert formula into cell if the cell to the right has text in it

Tags: excel, vba

The task I'm trying to accomplish is if Cells G21 to G27 have any text in them, then a vlookup formula will be pasted into the respective cell to the left of it

eg. Cell G31 has text so the formula `=VLOOKUP(G31,Data!$P$2:$Q$110,2,FALSE)` is in cell F31

This is the code I have so far, but I'm a beginner and I can't figure out how to insert the vlookup to automatically reference the cell next to it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Caps()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set SrchRng = Range("G31:G27")
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            cel.Offset(0, -1).Value= VLOOKUP(cel,Data!P2:Q110,2,FALSE)
        End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: If the cell has 'text' or it is not empty? I mean, are you referring to the cell format? Looking to your code, it looks to consider it "having text" if not empty. If so, do you want placing a formula, or calculating the `Vlookup` using VBA? Your code does not do/try any of the possible alternatives...

Comment: Should have clarified, the Vlookup should not be placed if the cell is empty. If it is not empty then the Vlookup should be placed in the cell directly to the left. I originally wanted it to calculate in the VBA, but I couldn't figure that out!

Comment: **Not empty***...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### VLookup vs Match

[image]

- Both solutions will write values (not formulas) since you wrote *"I originally wanted it to calculate in the VBA, but I couldn't figure that out!"* in the comments.

**A Quick Fix (Not Recommended)**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Caps()
    
    Dim SrchRng As Range: Set SrchRng = Range("G21:G27")
    Dim LkpRng As Range: Set LkpRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("P2:Q110")
    
    Dim SrchCell As Range
    Dim MatchValue As Variant
    For Each SrchCell In SrchRng.Cells
        If Len(CStr(SrchCell.Value)) > 0 Then
            MatchValue = Application.VLookup(SrchCell.Value, LkpRng, 2, False)
            If Not IsError(MatchValue) Then
                SrchCell.Offset(, -1).Value = MatchValue
            'Else
                'SrchCell.Offset(, -1).Value = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next SrchCell

End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

- The following uses the more flexible `Application.Match` instead of any 'flavor' of `VLookup`.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Performs a 'VLookup' using 'Application.Match'.
' Remarks:      Uses the 'RefColumn' and 'GetRange' functions.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub WorksheetCaps()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Data" ' Worksheet Name
    Const slFirst As String = "P2" ' First Lookup Cell Address
    Const svCol As String = "Q" ' Value Column
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1" ' Worksheet Name
    Const dlFirst As String = "G21" ' First Lookup Cell Address
    Const dvCol As String = "F" ' Value Column
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Lookup Range ('slrg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slfCell As Range: Set slfCell = sws.Range(slFirst)
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefColumn(slfCell)
    If slrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in source
    ' You can always use a static range instead of the previous 3 lines:
    'Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Range("P2:P110")
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Lookup Range ('dlrg').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlfCell As Range: Set dlfCell = dws.Range(dlFirst)
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = RefColumn(dlfCell)
    If dlrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in destination
    ' You can always use a static range instead of the previous 3 lines:
    'Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dws.Range("G21:G27")
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Value Range ('svrg').
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol)
    ' Write the values from the Source Value Range
    ' to the Source Value Array ('svData').
    Dim svData As Variant: svData = GetRange(svrg)
    
    ' Write the values from the Destination Lookup Range
    ' to the Destination Array ('dData').
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = GetRange(dlrg)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim smrIndex As Variant ' Source Match Row Index
    Dim dlValue As Variant ' Destination Lookup Value
    Dim dr As Long ' Destination Row Counter
    
    ' Loop through the elements (rows) of the Destination Array.
    For dr = 1 To UBound(dData, 1)
        ' Write the (lookup) value of the current element
        ' in the Destination Array to a variable ('dlValue').
        dlValue = dData(dr, 1)
        ' Replace the (lookup) value of the current element
        ' in the Destination Array with 'Empty'.
        dData(dr, 1) = Empty
        If Not IsError(dlValue) Then ' not an error value
            If Len(dlValue) > 0 Then ' not a blank
                ' Attempt to find a match of the current
                ' Destination Lookup value in the Source Lookup Range.
                smrIndex = Application.Match(dlValue, slrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(smrIndex) Then ' a match (the first occurrence)
                    ' Write the corresponding value (in the same row)
                    ' of the Source Lookup Range in the Source Value Array
                    ' to the current element in the Destination Array.
                    dData(dr, 1) = svData(smrIndex, 1)
                'Else  ' not a match (resulting in an error value)
                End If
            ' Else ' a blank: Empty, ="", ',...
            End If
        ' Else ' any error value
        End If
    Next dr
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Value Range ('dvrg').
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    ' Write the (modified) values from the Destination Array
    ' to the Destination Value Range (in one go).
    dvrg.Value = dData
    
    ' Save the workbook.
    wb.Save

    ' Inform the user.
    MsgBox "The lookup has finished successfully.", _
        vbInformation, "Worksheet Caps"
 
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

1. If you need to place a formula to calculate `Vlookup`, use the next way:

```
cel.Offset(0, -1).Formula2 = "=Vlookup(" & cel.Address & ",Data!P2:Q110,2,False)"
```

2. You you need to calculate `Vlookup` in VBA, use the next alternative:

```
cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cel.Value, Sheets("Data").Range("P2:Q110"), 2, False)
```

**Edited**:

Your whole code should should be adapted, in order to also deal with the case of no any match of `VLookup` function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Caps()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, VLKresult
    
    On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any matched cells
     Set SrchRng = Range("G31:G27").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'the range without empty cells
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not SrchRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In SrchRng
            VLKresult = Application.VLookup(cel.Value, Sheets("Data").Range("P$2:Q$110"), 2, False)
            If Not IsError(VLKresult) Then
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = VLKresult
            Else
                cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = "N/A"
            End If
       Next
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: I went with your second example and I'm now getting "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class." I'm assuming this is because some of the cells in the range are empty.

Comment: This should mean that Vlookup does not teturn anything for that cell value. Now I closed my laptop. I will show tomorrow how to deal with it, if not too late.